# SEt file permission in linux from home

Tags: linux, files, permissions, directory, home

I am in my home directory. 
I want to set file permission for my file named "Secret" so that no others can read or write this file.
I want to do this by the symbolic method.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Also in your own interest you should make a good-faith attempt at solving it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is owned by you and your group:

```
chown youruser.yourgroup Secret
```

Make sure that no one who is in your group 'g', or 'o'ther people can 'r'ead, 'w'rite, or e'x'ecute the file. the '-' means, 'take away' the permissions. So go-rwx means, from 'g'roup and 'o'ther ,  'take away' the r, w, and x permissions.

```
chmod go-rwx Secret
```

Comment: I've improved it